# Optional order by in prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm refactoring my application. One thing that I'm actually doing is:

```
String sql = "select column1 from table2";
boolean isOrderbyAdded = false;
for(int i=1; i<N; i++) { // N is a known integer (e.g. 5)
    if(column[i]!=null) {
        if(!isOrderbyAdded) {
            sql += " order by "
            isOrderbyAdded = true;
        } else {
            sql += ", "
        }
        sql += column[i];
    }
}
```

I want to change this into a prepared statement. Is there a way to write one statement that checks whether each column name was specified before eventually sorting the results?

My query is executed millions of time a day. I thought that a prepared statement would save me some compilation time.

Comment: since you are _refactoring_, change `orderby_added` to `isOrderbyAdded ` :)

Comment: In a prepared statement just the where of your query will change. The order by still in the same way.

Comment: @SérgioMichels, so there is no way to avoid recompiling this statement every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be done using basic SQL libraries. You're stuck, but you have a few options.

1. Using `String.format` may be faster for you.
2. Using a `StringBuilder` with `.append` will **definitely** be faster for you.

   - Don't ever use += for `String`s, unless it's not done very often (then it doesn't matter). `StringBuilder` is always faster, especially if you can predict the [`capacity`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder%28int%29) well. But the default of 16 more characters is likely to be sufficient here (though, if it's not, use a larger one).
3. Probably the fastest would be to start using Spring. i.e. use this [sort](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html) class.

Here's the version of your code that uses `StringBuilder`, though the Spring way is probably best, but would require a lot more work on your part. [Check out Spring here.](http://www.springsource.org)

```
StringBuilder sqlsb = new StringBuilder("select column1 from table2");
boolean isOrderbyAdded = false;
for(int i=1; i<N; i++) { // N is a known integer (e.g. 5)
  if(column[i]!=null) {
    if(!isOrderbyAdded) {
      sqlsb.append(" order by ");
          isOrderbyAdded = true;
    } else {
      sqlsb.append(", ");
    }
    sqlsb.append(column[i]);
  }
}
String sql = sqlsb.toString();
```

Comment: Not that the cost of building the SQL string will be even remotely significant when compared to the cost of talking to the database. While your code is definitely faster, the original code runs a million times in less than three seconds on my antique laptop.

Comment: @gustafc: I assume his actual query is much longer than 26 characters in the real world. Every time you do `+=` on an (immutable) `String`, it has to copy the ENTIRE string over.

Comment: Correct, and insignificant. You won't notice it because most of the time is spent talking TCP to the DB server.

Comment: Well, right, but things like LRC cache and optimizing the queries themselves are beyond the scope of his question.

Comment: My concern was not about the overhead of String manipulation. It was, instead, about the reusability of the prepared statement. I accept "not possible" as an answer.

Comment: @mossaab: Well, right, that's why I included the stuff about Spring. But default Java doesn't do what you want, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the SELECT columns are the candidates for the ORDER BY columns.

So: **you are having a half DB model in java**, and if you are not going for a fuller model, you could have a pool of written out SQL statements in XML, like in [mybatis](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/wiki/Welcome). Collecting the SQLs, and grouping them by table might help.

Going for a full model: in JPA (using for instance eclipseLink), you have a criteria api for type safe building of queries.

However refactory of legacy code should *before any improvements* make old things clean and maintainable.
Splitting data query
 from representation, removing ugly nested loops of queries, Collecting queries on the same table. And such.

And yes, using prepared statements is better, if only for SQL injection and escaping of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> My query is executed millions of time a day. I thought that a prepared statement would save me some compilation time.

What do you mean by "compiling"? If you mean building the SQL string, the cost of talking to the database will always dominate the string building (I ran your original code a million times in less than three seconds). Worry about making that part of the code readable instead.

A more important concern is whether the query plan will be cached properly - which it probably is, albeit with a separate cache entry for every combination of sort orders. That's not very strange, since the sort order may well change the execution plan.